# Qt/QML qmlRegisterType vs. setContextProperty (difference)

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In Qt/QML application (this code usually resides in `main.cpp` of QtCreator project), what is the difference between following ways of exposing C++ class to QML:

```
qmlRegisterType<UePeopleModel>("com.example",
                               1,
                               0,
                               "UePeopleModel");
```

and

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                         uePeopleModel);
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**qmlRegisterType** :

"Sometimes a QObject-derived class may need to be registered with the QML type system but not as an instantiable type."

Use qmlRegisterType, if you want reuse a QObject-derived class with in one or more than one qml file with different property. QML is responsible for initialization of this register class.

See this for more help.
[Defining QML Types from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html)

**setContextProperty** :

Use setContextProperty, When you want to use a single global class to access to or from QML. Here You need create this class object before use setContextProperty().

Note: Since all expressions evaluated in QML are evaluated in a particular context, if the context is modified, all bindings in that context will be re-evaluated. Thus, context properties should be used with care outside of application initialization, as this may lead to decreased application performance.

See this for more help.
[Embedding C++ Objects into QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html)

Comment: so I have Qt/QML and this app at the beginning requires user login. I am thinking of creating some global status class, which will contain (at the beginning) id and name of logged user (taken from database) so for this particular example I embedded object into qml rather than defining new qml type?

Comment: Yes, setContextProperty() is best option.

Comment: [This](https://forum.qt.io/post/212826) post covers also the comparison between Context Properties and Singletons.

Answer (score 4):

In the first one you are declaring a C++ type available for instantiation in QML, in the second you are declaring a global variable "uePeopleModel" of the same type.