# How to get a valid instance of a QQuickItem on C++ side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qquickitem

Alright. I have searched a lot but haven't got a good solution yet. I am new to `Qt`. I have a class which is a `QQuickItem` like so,

```
class MyQuickItemClass : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    SetInfo(SomeCppClass object)
};
```

I do a `qmlRegisterType` in my `main.cpp` to register it on the `qml` side like this,

qmlRegisterType< MyQuickItemClass >("MyQuickItemClass", 1, 0, "MyQuickItemClass");

All fine till here. But -> I want to set an object instance & some properties in MyQuickItemClass which some C++ logic in it as well & then pass the `MyQuickItemClass` object to `qml`. Or, get a valid instance of `MyQuickItemClass` from Qml. **How can I get a vlid instance `MyQuickItemClass` object instance from `QML` on C++ side in `main.cpp` ?**

I tried doing the following learning from the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044270/qt-qml-qmlregistertype-vs-setcontextproperty-difference). But this technique creates two separate objects of `MyQuickItemClass`. One from `QML`, & one from `c++` side. Hence does not work for me.

Following is how I am trying to do this after lot of searching.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  qmlRegisterType< MyQuickItemClass >("MyQuickItemClass", 1, 0, "MyQuickItemClass");
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  SomeCppClass someCppClassObject;
  someCppClassObject.updateSomething();

  MyQuickItemClass myquickItemObject;
  myquickItemObject.SetInfo(someCppClassObject);
  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myquickItemObject", &myquickItemObject);

  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
  return app.exec();
}
```

*But, doing the above gets the constructor of `MyQuickItemClass` called twice. Once from `cpp` side when I created an object, and once from `qml` side. Verified this by placing a breakpoint in the constructor of `MyQuickItemClass` as well. As a result, `someCppClassObject` that I had set is null inside `MyQuickItemClass` when program runs. Because qml has made the final call to `MyQuickItemClass` to instantiate, thusly ignoring the `MyQuickItemClass` object that I created in `main.cpp`.*

Here is my `qml` code for `MyQuickItemClass`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import MyQuickItemClass 1.0

ParentContainerItem {
  id: parentItem
  color: "black"

  MyQuickItemClass {
      id: myQuickItemID
      visible: true
      objectName: "myQuickItem"

      property bool someProperty1: false
      property bool someProperty2: true

      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
  }

  //Other qml components
}
```

And this is the C++ class whose object needs to be set into `MyQuickItemClass`.

```
SomeCppClass {
  //Pure C++ class. No Qt
}
```

Please note that I need to keep `MyQuickItemClass` derived from `QQuickItem`. Please suggest...

Comment: what error do you get? how is the instance "invalid"?

Comment: the constructor of `MyQuickItemClass` gets called twice. Once from `cpp` side when I created an object, and once from `qml` side. Verified this by placing a breakpoint in the constructor of `MyQuickItemClass` as well. As a result, `someCppClassObject` that I had set is null inside `MyQuickItemClass` when program runs. Because `qml` has made the final call to `MyQuickItemClass` to instantiate, thusly ignoring the `MyQuickItemClass` object that I created in `main.cpp`

Comment: You should add the error to the question too. So people who find this question don't have to read through the comments for this.

Comment: Ok. added the error to the question now

Comment: show us the main.qml

Comment: Why do you recreate it in QML? You can just access your c++ object via `myquickItemObject` in your qml file.

Comment: I updated qml part of my code into the question

Comment: @GrecKo please note that `SomeCppClass` is a pure C++ class

Comment: you can simply  instantiate your `myQuickItemObject` from main.qml  as GrecKo says and then pass it as a QObject via signal/slots from qml to C++ and vice versa

Comment: @MikeNickaloff . Can you pls explain what you mean by `instantiate myQuickItemObject` ? Is it by creating a block like this in in `qml` ?   
        `myQuickItemObject {
            id: myobject
        }`

Isnt `myQuickItemObject` already instantiated in qml ?

Comment: @NelsonP you already created it in c++, doing `SomeCppClass { }` in qml will create another instance of it. Just access it via `myQuickItemObject` as if it were its' `id`.

Comment: Imagine anytime you register a class using `qmlRegisterType<>()` that you are basically adding a new class-type to QML. It does not matter if that class-type is totally written in C++ or not, you access its methods the same way as in C++ from QML.  That being said, all QML items have to be QObject derived, so you can pass an instance of a QML-instantiated object as a QObject to a native C++ typed object by adding to the root context of the QML engine and then passing the desired object via a regular slot;   `void send_qml_object(QObject* qmlObject)` from qml: `cppObj.send_qml_object(myobject)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is a good idea to avoid accessing QML instantiated objects `from outside` as most of the access methods generated a dependency from C++ toward QML, restricting the way the QML tree is done.

E.g. requiring certain objects to exist at certain point in times, having specific `objectName` values, etc.

It is better to either "register" the object from QML side by calling a method on an exposed C++ object/API or to make the QML instantiate object register itself from within its own C++ code.

The latter is obviously inherently automatic, i.e. each instance of such a class would do that, while the former puts it at the discretion of the QML code which of the created instances it wants to make known.

Comment: Isn't there any way to get a valid instance of `MyQuickItemClass` from the qml objects tree & facilitate myself to call the method `SetInfo` ? Strange !! I thought this would be really simple

Comment: There is, simply search for the object given its object name using `QObject::findChild()`, but why do that if there are much cleaner ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following from a suggestion in discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195129/how-to-set-a-pure-c-object-instance-in-a-qquickitem) solves the issue & gets a valid object to the QuickItem qml file

```
QQuickItem *myItem = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem *>("myQuickItem");
```