# How to get a C++ object instance of a QQuickItem on C++ side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qquickitem

I have `QtApp` & a pure C++ library. The C++ library exposes a one simple class called `MyCppLibApiClass`. The `QtApp` has a class which is embedded on `main.qml`. Following is the class:

```
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem {
  MyQuickItem();
}
```

Following the `qml` code for the `quick item`:

```
import MyQuickItem 1.0

MyQuickItem {
  id: myQuickItemID
  visible: true
  objectName: "myQuickItem"
}
```

Following is my `main.cpp` showing I load the `qml` item:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyQuickItem>("MyQuickItem", 1, 0, "MyQuickItem");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
```

`MyQuickItem` needs access to `MyCppLibApiClass` instance. **How do a I get a valid instance to `MyQuickItem` in `main.cpp` ?** I need to set an object of `MyCppLibApiClass` as member in `MyQuickItem`. I can do this using a setter method. But, first of all I need to get a valid instance to `MyQuickItem`. So **How to get access to `MyQuickItem` in `main.cpp` ?**

**EDIT:**
I have searched quite a before asking this question. I read through this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#accessing-loaded-qml-objects-by-object-name). Also, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178332/how-to-get-a-valid-instance-of-a-qquickitem-on-c-side) question posted by me, did not get me an accurate answer. Hence, rephrasing my question more clearly to try get an answer. Appreciate suggestions to this..

Comment: To expose your class to QML you should derive it from at least QObject (or from QQuickItem if that's visible item). In another case you can wrap it into QObject and so expose it to QML using `qmlRegisterType`

Comment: as you see in my question, I've already derived `MyQuickItem` from `QQuickItem`. Now, how should I get access to `MyQuickItem`'s instance in `main.cpp` ?

Comment: what does that mean? if you expose your class to QML with `qmlRegisterType` you shouldn't instance it. It will be instanced by QML.

Comment: My question is: How do I get access to that instance of `MyQuickItem` which QML has created after call to `qmlRegisterType`.

Comment: Or is there some other way to instance `MyQuickItem` in QML so that I can have access to its object in `main.cpp` ?

Comment: Ah .. get it now. Just assign `objectName` to QML item and so do `QQuickItem *myItem = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem *>("myQuickItem");`

Comment: After getting access to `myItem` in the way you described, will I be able to call a method which I have exposed to set the pure cpp class object ? Like so: `myItem.setPureCppClassObject(cppObeject)` ?

Comment: @NelsonP - of course, it is C++ you can call anything that is public.

Comment: @folibis thanks. I will try this out

Comment: So basically you repeated the question in hope to get answers you like better?
And it turned out that the the answers where exactly the same you had on the previous question?
Maybe you should take that as s hint that those answers are what you are looking for even if you insist on looking for something else?

Comment: @KevinKrammer. My question were different. I did not want to get answer to 2-3 additional questions after asking one. Hence created separate distinct questions

Comment: @KevinKrammer Not sure why this question was downvoted. This discussion on this page has lot of useful information around this topic of accessing a QuickItem's object

Comment: @folibis I tried your suggestion: `QQuickItem *myItem = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem *>("myQuickItem");` It works nicely. Thanks

Comment: @NelsonP likely because it is a duplicate. Wasting everyone's time by repeatedly asking the same question is likely frowned upon.

Comment: @KevinKrammer You can see clearly in the previous question that I did not receive any answers at all. Then I asked this question. If it wasnt for this discussion, I would not have got my answer.  I agreed that its a duplicate question but this is the question that gave me my answer & also multiple options :) Is there any way to flag up a question if I am not getting any attention on it ?

Comment: @NelsonP Interesting. Somehow we seem to get different outputs then. I see an answer on the other question but maybe it is because the answer is from myself and somehow hidden to others?
Hmm, no, you commented on it so you must have seen it. The answer even has a comment that mentions the hack that you seem to prefer over a clean and maintainable solution.
Did the answer suddenly disappear for you?

Comment: @KevinKrammer. not sure what you asking, but anyways I agree. a duplicate question is a duplicate by the rules :) Yep. But there have been many good suggestions in both of my questions. I need to try the best solution. as of now, i am just doing what works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a single instance of your library object, there are two ways you can go about it depending on what kind of access you need:

- have the instance as a static member of the `MyQuickItem` class, initialize it in `main.cpp` before you create the QML application, then you can access it from inside `MyQuickItem` in C++.
- have the instance inherit `QObject` and expose it as a context property, this way it can be accessed from QML.

If it is not a singleton object, you have two courses of action:

- create the QML object from C++, it will give you direct pointer to it
- find the QML object in the object tree by using [`QQmlApplicationEngine::rootObjects().at(0).findChild()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) for the type and object name, if found you will have a pointer to the object

However, as one of the answers of the questions you have liked suggests, this is not really considered recommended practice. There is probably a better way to do that, you shouldn't be doing setting QML object properties in main.cpp, it should be either in the constructor or public interface of `MyQuickItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this.Can I expose `setproperty` in `MyQuickItem` which accepts a pure C++ class ? Can you please provide some reference projects on github or somewhere doing the same ?

Comment: You can pass around opaque non-QObject derived C++ types in QML as parameter and return values if you `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(YourType)` That is if you need to do it from QML, from C++ you have full access to the object's public interface, you can do as you please. But again, you are **doing it wrong**. It may not matter now, but sooner or later it will. Bad design is always terrible long term.

Comment: What do you recommend the best way to do this ? I have `pure C++ library` exposing a pure cpp class with an api. I cannot afford to put qt into the cpp library. All I need is to set this cpp library class into the qml quick item class.  Are there any code samples on github I can refer to ? it will be great if can provide some code samples pls

Comment: @NelsonP - your usage scenario is unknown, so I can't get a specific advise. However, what is wrong with using your library from C++ INSIDE `MyQuickItem` instead of main.cpp? Sounds like that's what you should be doing.

Comment: I am new to Qt. I have to try out the suggestions before I answer or ask for any other info. I will come back after trying out things. thanks a lot for your attention on this.

Comment: @NelsonP - if you can do it in main.cpp you can do it in the constructor or in a slot of `MyQuickItem`.

Comment: Last question : If make a slot in `MyQuickItem` to accept an instance of `MyPureCppClassObeject`, then can I make the slot with `MyPureCppClassObeject` as a type or do I need to use a `QVariant` ?

Comment: You only need the variant wrapper if you are calling from QML and passing the parameter there. On the C++ side you don't need that sugar.

Comment: @ddriver waste of time, he is stuck in his line of thinking that he can't comprehend how your valuable input would lead him to an actually maintainable solution.

Comment: @KevinKrammer Knowledge is the product of but no substitute to experience. Some things can't be learned from teaching the way they can be learned from trying.

Answer (score 3):

in your main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyQuickItem>("MyQuickItem", 1, 0, "MyQuickItem");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
MyQuickItem myItem;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myItem", &myItem);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
```

Now you can access myItem from C++ and access that same myItem from QML, simply by setting the property "myItem" on  the root level of the QML context to be a reference to your custom object.

**EDIT**

I added the qmlRegisterType  declaration to the answer.

As per request in comment:

Using qmlRegisterType<>()   is used to register a specific type in QML which can then be created/accessed from QML.

By using the `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myItem", &myItem)` 
method you are actually creating `myItem` in C++ and setting the ownership of `myItem` to C++

Since QML is designed to work with C++, it is possible to simply assign `myItem` as a property in QML and since QML automatically inherits properties/objects from parent objects, then `myItem` becomes available in the entire QML context.

**Neither of the two examples have been tested, and are simply to demonstrate the idea**

**Example main.qml**

```
import MyQuickItem 1.0

Item {
   Component.onCompleted {
        myItem.visible = true;
        myItem.myCustomMethod();
   }
}
```

**Example C++ Class**

```
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem {


     MyQuickItem();

 public slots: 
    void myCustomMethod() { /* do some C++ stuff here */ }

 }
```

Comment: my answer was really just ddriver's answer only written out in code, so to understand it better refer to ddriver's answer above

Comment: thanks for code. I see that you are not doing a `qmlRegisterType<MyQuickItem>("MyQuickItem", 1, 0, "MyQuickItem")`. If I dont do this, then Qt doesnt allow me to do a `import MyQuickItem 1.0`. hence, bars me from declaring `MyQuickItem` in `main.qml` at all. `qmlRegisterType` is not required anymore ? Can you please provide the `qml` part of the code around `MyQuickItem`?