# Connect QAbstractTableModel with QML TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have subclassed the `QAbstractItemModel` in order to create a very generic model, here are the files:

cvartablemodel.h

```
#ifndef CVARTABLEMODEL_H
#define CVARTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QList>
#include <QVariant>

/**
 * @brief   Provides a QAbstractTableModel override class that implements the
 *          API for MDE variables storing, reading and writing.
 */
class CVarTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{

public:

    /**
     * @brief   An enumeration class providing the columns and the amount of
     *          columns as well (use ZCOUNT as always last member).
     */
    enum class Columns
    {
        Name = 0,
        Unit,
        Value,

        ZCOUNT,
    };
    Q_ENUM(Columns)

    CVarTableModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~CVarTableModel() override;

    // Basic overrides
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    // Since its a well behaved model...
    QVariant headerData(int section,
                        Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role) const override;

    // Its an editable model
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index,
                 const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    // Only rows are modificable for now
    bool insertRows(int position,
                    int rows,
                    const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex()) override;
    bool removeRows(int position,
                    int rows,
                    const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex()) override;

private:

    /**
     * @brief   The local, intermediate storage object.
     */
    QList<QList<QVariant>> m_data;
};

#endif // CVARTABLEMODEL_H
```

cvartablemodel.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>

#include "cvartablemodel.h"

/**
 * @brief   The default constructor, nothing interesting in here.
 * @param   parent: the parent object.
 */
CVarTableModel::CVarTableModel(QObject* parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{

}

/**
 * @brief   Clear the storage and remove connections (if any) at exit
 */
CVarTableModel::~CVarTableModel()
{
    foreach (auto row, m_data)
        row.clear();

    m_data.clear();
}

/**
 * @brief   Returns the fixed (for now) amount of columns
 * @param   parent: unused
 * @return  The amount of available columns
 */
int CVarTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0; // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#columnCount

    return static_cast<int>(Columns::ZCOUNT);
}

/**
 * @brief   Row count is equal to the stored number of variables.
 * @param   parent: unused.
 * @return  The amount of stored variables entries.
 */
int CVarTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0; // https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount

    return m_data.length();
}

/**
 * @brief   Reads the cell specified by the \ref index.
 * @param   index: Stores row/ col data.
 * @param   role: the display role.
 * @return  In case of valid \p index, a valid cell value. Otherwise empty
 *          QVariant object.
 */
QVariant CVarTableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    // check the row
    if ((index.row() >= m_data.length()) || (index.row() < 0))
        return QVariant();

    // check the column
    if ((index.row() >= m_data[index.row()].length()) || (index.column() < 0))
        return QVariant();

    return m_data[index.row()][index.column()];
}

/**
 * @brief   Obtains the header (columns) names.
 * @param   section: column number.
 * @param   orientation: Accepts only horizontal.
 * @param   role: Accepts only display.
 * @return  The column header text in case all params are valid.
 *          Otherwise empty QVariant.
 */
QVariant CVarTableModel::headerData(int section,
                                    Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                    int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (orientation != Qt::Horizontal)
        return QVariant();

    if (section >= static_cast<int>(Columns::ZCOUNT))
        return QVariant();

    return QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<Columns>(section));
}

/**
 * @brief   Returns the \p index flags. Only values column is editable for now.
 * @param   index: model index item.
 * @return  flags enum val.
 */
Qt::ItemFlags CVarTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

    if (index.isValid())
    {
        if (static_cast<Columns>(index.column()) == Columns::Value)
            flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    return flags;
}

/**
 * @brief   Cell data writing override.
 * @param   index: The model index with row/ col.
 * @param   value: Value to be set in the cell.
 * @param   role: Only EditRole accepted.
 * @return  Non zero on succesfull data editing.
 */
bool CVarTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index,
                             const QVariant& value,
                             int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid() || (role != Qt::EditRole))
        return false;

    // check the row
    if ((index.row() >= m_data.length()) || (index.row() < 0))
        return false;

    // check the column
    if ((index.row() >= m_data[index.row()].length()) || (index.column() < 0))
        return false;

    m_data[index.row()][index.column()] = value;
    emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});

    return true;
}

/**
 * @brief   Inserts the \p rows amount of rows. They will start at \p position.
 * @param   position: position at which the insertion starts (the new 1st item
 *          will have this index in the end).
 * @param   rows: amount of rows to insert.
 * @param   index: unused.
 * @return  Non zero in case of succesfull row insertion.
 */
bool CVarTableModel::insertRows(int position,
                                int rows,
                                const QModelIndex& index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);

    if ((position >= rowCount(QModelIndex())) || (position < 0))
        return false;

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        QList<QVariant> emptyRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount(QModelIndex()); i++)
            emptyRow.append(QVariant());

        m_data.insert(position, emptyRow);
    }
    endInsertRows();

    return true;
}

/**
 * @brief   Removes \p rows amount of rows starting at \p position
 * @param   position: removing starts at this position.
 * @param   rows: the amount of rows that will be removed.
 * @param   index: unused.
 * @return  Non zero on succesfull rows removal.
 */
bool CVarTableModel::removeRows(int position,
                                int rows,
                                const QModelIndex& index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);

    if ((position >= rowCount(QModelIndex())) || (position < 0))
        return false;

    if (rows > rowCount(QModelIndex()))
        return false;

    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        m_data.removeAt(position);

    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

I need to connect an instance of this object with the QML `TableView` component and I am really not sure how.

I have created the instance and a getter for it:

```
    /**
     * @brief   The API + intermediate storage model for the bad nodes
     */
    CVarTableModel m_varTabModel;

/**
 * @brief   A pointer getter for the whole variable table model.
 * @return  pointer to the model.
 */
QObject* CVessel::varTabModel()
{
    return static_cast<QObject*>(&m_varTabModel);
}
```

So initially this would need to be a 3 column table with no rows (some rows could be added in the constructor for testing purposes).

How can a `TableView` component on the QML side utilize this now? I would appreciate some QML examples of a TableView allowing to enter and edit some values.

Answer (score 1):

A QML TableView uses the roles instead of column number. If you check the column in the model passed to the method `data()`, you will see that it's always at 0.

So, you have to convert the role given in the TableView and the column number in your model.

You could use a proxy model to handle the role/column conversion. You'll not have to change your current model:

The `QIdentityProxyModel` class is a good to base for that:

```
class QMLProxy: public QIdentityProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    QMLProxy(QObject* parent=nullptr): QIdentityProxyModel(parent)
    {}

    enum Role
    {
        NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        UnitRole
    };
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[NameRole] = "COL1";
        roles[UnitRole] = "COL2";
        return roles;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override
      {
        QModelIndex newIndex = mapIndex(index, role);
        if (role == NameRole || role == UnitRole)
            role = Qt::DisplayRole;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::data(newIndex, role);
      }

    Q_INVOKABLE void edit(int row,
                             const QVariant &value,
                             QString const& role)
    {
        if (role == QString(roleNames().value(NameRole)))
            setData(createIndex(row, 0), value, Qt::EditRole);
        else if (role == QString(roleNames().value(UnitRole)))
            setData(createIndex(row, 1), value, Qt::EditRole);
    }

private:
    QModelIndex mapIndex(QModelIndex const& source, int role) const {
        switch(role)
        {
        case NameRole:
            return createIndex(source.row(), 0);
        case UnitRole:
            return createIndex(source.row(), 1);
        }
        return source;
    }
};
```

I overrided the `data()` to convert the role to the column number. And I created a method `edit` because when it will be called from the QML, the signature will be different than the method `setData`.

To pass the model to the QML from the main:

```
CVarTableModel* model = new CVarTableModel();

QMLProxy* proxy = new QMLProxy();
proxy->setSourceModel(model);

QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", proxy);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
view->show();
```

Then, in the QML, you need a delegate to make your table editable (I used a TextInput. But, you can use another component):

```
TableView {
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "COL1"
        title: "Col 1"
        width: 100
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "COL2"
        title: "Col 2"
        width: 200
    }
    model: myModel
    itemDelegate: Component {
        TextInput {
          id:textinput
          text: styleData.value
          onAccepted: {
                  myModel.edit(styleData.row, text, styleData.role)
          }
          MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: textinput.forceActiveFocus()
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `mapIndex` do? Is it a helper function?

Comment: The column in your index will always be 0 when `data()` is called from the QML TableView. `mapIndex` should return a new index with the right column according to the role (NameRole, UnitRole, etc.). I edited my answer to provide a minimal implementation of `mapIndex`